# How should I turn a lambda expression into code (text)?

Tags: c#, lambda

What is the 'proper' or 'best' way to turn a `System.Linq.LambdaExpression` into compilable code? I have a 'query language' for my application that will convert search expressions into lambdas. I am working on a code generator and I am trying to leverage this query language to generate validation expressions. `Expression.ToString()` uses `ExpressionStringBuilder`, which converts some nodes to things other than valid C#, such as 'AndAlso' and 'OrElse' instead of the operators `&&` and `||`. Ideally I would override `ExpressionStringBuilder`, but it is internal.

Comment: The best way to turn it into compiled code is to call `Compile`.  If you want to turn it into valid uncompiled C# code instead, then that's certainly no small task; well beyond the scope of an SO answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement an expression tree visitor to translate all the nodes into code. See *[How to: Implement an Expression Tree Visitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)* (MSDN).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that... Oh well.