# Get function information from expression tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees

For documentary purposes, I want to automatically capture the functions called in my code and save them as a string to write down in my log.

This works nicely if I just use plain lambdas, for example:

```
Expression<Func<double, bool>> lambda = x => x < 0;
Console.WriteLine(lambda.Parameters[0].Name);
Console.WriteLine(lambda.Body);
```

I get:

x

(x < 0)

But if I use other variables, it looks much more inconvenient:

```
int factor = 2;
Expression<Func<double, bool>> lambda = x => x * factor < 0;
Console.WriteLine(lambda.Parameters[0].Name);
Console.WriteLine(lambda.Body);
```

This will give:

x

((x * Convert(value(MyProg.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).factor)) < 0)

In principle, I can regex myself out of this to reach a result like x * factor < 0, but is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27407511/5133585). I don't think you can avoid implementing an `ExpressionVisitor` that handles everything that can appear in your lambdas. See how `Expression.ToString` does it [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/ExpressionStringBuilder.cs,6b904e11268a6d80). You basically need to do something similar, with your own custom changes.

Comment: Note that captured local variables are translated to fields in a generated structure. Included in the expression as a constant. Or you can just use https://www.nuget.org/packages/AgileObjects.ReadableExpressions/